# Registering udf in excel 2003 addin

Tags: excel, vba

When I add some description to udf in Excel 2003 like:

```
Application.MacroOptions _
Macro:= "MyMacro", _
Category:= "MyCategory" _
Description:= "MyDesc"
```

and save the workbook as ***.xla** to my addin directory, the udf is registering correct when the add in is installed. But if I close the excel and open it again, the udf is still available, but disappears from function wisard.

If I place the registration code above to `Workbook_Open` excel reports the error: can't modify the hidden workbook.
If I place the registration code to `AddInInstall` it works only once when addin is installed (or I need uncheck the addin in the addin list and check it again)

How to make udf registered permanently, every time addin is loaded?

Comment: Hi. I have [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41465478/4636801). Maybe you will find some solution there.